# mongodb find document within the geometry with variable radius

Tags: mongodb

mongodb document have this data:

```
{
"_id":ObjectId("5e96fd8fcb263f0599028c93")
"address": [
        {
            "name": "address1",
            "myradius":100,
            "geom": {
                    "type": "Point",
                    "coordinates": [
                        -73.99279,
                        40.719296
                    ]
                }
        }
    ]

.....
}
```

i want to write query to find all document that within the bounds of the circle with myradius radius like this:

```
db.test.find("
{
"address.0.geom":  
   {
      $geoWithin: 
     {
        $centerSphere: [[ -73,40 ],myradius]}
     }
  }
")
```

problem is how to use `myradius` in query?

Comment: The way you describe didn't work for you?

Comment: [Error] ReferenceError: myradius is not defined

Comment: And if you define `myradius` before making that call?

Comment: myradius is a field of document

Comment: Ah, I missed that. So are you trying to link 2 collections?  Is that document in the collection you are searching?